# How to query username, its roles and its roles privileges?

Tags: postgresql

I have tried to query the user, the roles that it has and the privileges that the roles that it has have. I have managed to query the user and roles that it has with the following select:

```
SELECT pg_user.usename, pg_roles.rolname
FROM pg_user
JOIN pg_auth_members ON pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN pg_roles ON pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid;
```

But I still would like to query the privileges of the roles of the users. I think I should join the table role_table_grants and select its column privilege_type, but I have not been able to output what I would like. It gave me zero rows as output.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT pg_user.usename, pg_roles.rolname, role_table_grants.privilege_type
FROM pg_user
JOIN pg_auth_members ON pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN pg_roles ON pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid
JOIN information_schema.role_table_grants ON role_table_grants.grantee = pg_roles.rolname;
```

Does anyone know how I could do it?

Another detail: when I run this select, I get some users and their roles as output:

```
SELECT pg_user.usename, pg_roles.rolname
FROM pg_user
JOIN pg_auth_members ON pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN pg_roles ON pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid;
```

But when I run this select, I get totally different roles from what I get with the previous select:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because in you query there is no direct mapping between PostgreSQL's system tables and the information_schema.role_table_grants table. If you want to get more data about privileges on tables, utilize the pg_table_privileges system catalog table instead.
Try this updated code :

```
SELECT 
    pg_user.usename,
    pg_roles.rolname,
    pg_table_privileges.privilege_type,
    pg_table_privileges.table_name
FROM 
    pg_user
JOIN 
    pg_auth_members ON pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN 
    pg_roles ON pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_table_privileges ON pg_roles.rolname = pg_table_privileges.grantee;
```

To obtain data on users, the roles of users, and the table privileges, the above updated SQL query joins the pg_user, pg_auth_members, pg_roles, and pg_table_privileges databases. Columns for user name, role name, privilege type, and associated table name are included in the result, and the LEFT JOIN guarantees that roles without explicit table privileges are included.

Hope it's helpful :)